# Unable to list S3 buckets in AWS CLI despite having Full access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information on this... What is the aws cli command you tried and environment?

Comment: If that is the actual statement, and not a typo, I'm not sure the statement is even valid. Your action is `s3:`, but it should be `s3:*` to grant full access.

Comment: Please post the error you are getting when you using `aws s3 ls` command? cross check the access and secret key using are belong to the right user with the mentioned policy.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please provide a **[Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (min-reprex)**, and show us what you want, what you're currently getting, or your current error message, and what you've tried so far, also see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also see [**How to write a perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question)

Comment: Thank you all. Issue is resolved.

I happened to attach a MFA Policy. This was applying to both Console and CLI. Hence was unable to authorize despite having full access.

Whenever You attach a MFA Policy. Make sure it is excluded of CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You need some * in your statement.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you all. Issue is resolved. I happened to attach a MFA Policy. This was applying to both Console and CLI. Hence was unable to authorize despite having full access. Whenever You attach a MFA Policy. Make sure it is excluded of CLI.